# react-router web server for dev

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-router

I'm just getting started using react-router and I want to use browserHistory. Until now I've been developing using hot reloading with watchify and a chrome plugin to monitor for changes in my static content. That means that I'm doing all my dev directly on static content and refreshing that static content in the browser with no web server involved.

Now begins the challenge - you can't use browserHistory on a file:// because the origin is null and the history api throws an error. Additionally, browserHistory is better and recommended so I want to use it. The trouble is it breaks my dev workflow. It's going to be very slow if every time I need to test a change I have to deploy my static content to my local tomcat instance.

I think the NPM community must already have a solution for this and I just don't know what tool to search for. I think there must be some NPM plugin that monitors for changes in my SPA content, builds it, and then deploys it to a webserver. I did some searches for such a tool but I haven't found what I needed so far.

Can anyone assist? I think maybe I just need Grunt to automatically push to my local tomcat... Whatever the solution I need a fast dev workflow. :)

Comment: Grunt could certainly be used here. I would recommend checking out webpack - https://webpack.github.io - as it's one of if not the most popular bundlers at the moment. I have a similar setup for a project, where webpack (launched through NPM) watches for changes in my source files and exports bundles to the chosen directory. Webpack also has its own dev server but it's optional.

Comment: Yea I've not been sure which I should learn, webpack or grunt. Tons of frameworks and tools to learn, it takes time. What made you choose webpack - just popularity?

Comment: Popularity didn't hurt. But what led me there the fastest was Dan Abramov's hot reloading tools which (at least the first version of) relied on webpack. But there's certainly a lot of tooling out there and even more opinions on how to combine them together. I don't find much of a need for gulp or grunt these days - just npm scripts and webpack.

Comment: Seconding what @Yair - since I started using Webpack, I don't really find much use for task runners any more. Most things can be done through Webpack plugins/loaders, and anything that can't, I just tend to make an NPM script in my package.json.

Comment: Cool, I've actually wanted to stay pure npm but wasn't sure if that would be doing it the hard way. You guys have any good references for a hot reloading toolset without grunt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a gulp task with watchify and browsersync to do so. Here's how it might look:

Notice the historyApiFallback() which allow the use of browserHistory.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var watchify = require('watchify');
var historyApiFallback = require('connect-history-api-fallback');
var htmltidy = require('gulp-htmltidy');
var filesize = require('gulp-filesize');
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var csslint = require('gulp-csslint');
var assign = require('lodash.assign');

var customOpts = {
  entries: ['./src/js/app.js'],
  transform: [
    [
      'babelify',
      {
        'plugins': ['transform-decorators-legacy'],
        'presets': ['es2015', 'react', 'stage-0']
      }
    ],
    'brfs'
  ],
  debug: true,
  cache: {},
  packageCache: {},
  fullPaths: true
};

var opts = assign({}, watchify.args, customOpts);
var bundler = browserify(opts);

function bundle() {
  return bundler
      .bundle()
      .pipe(source('app.js'))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(filesize())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.init({loadMaps: true}))
      .pipe(filesize())
      .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js'));
}
gulp.task('serve', ['js', 'css'], function() {
  var watch = watchify(bundler);
  // Without the line, update events won't be fired
  watch.bundle().on('data', function() {});

  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'dist',
      middleware: [historyApiFallback()]
    },
    port: 8000,
    ui: {
      port: 8001
    }
  });

  gulp.watch(['*.html'], {cwd: 'src'}, ['html', browserSync.reload]);
  gulp.watch(['css/**/*.css'], {cwd: 'src'}, ['css', browserSync.reload]);
  bundler.on('update', bundle); // on any dep update, runs the bundler
  gulp.watch(['js/**/*.js'], {cwd: 'dist'}, browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('js', bundle);

gulp.task('css', function () {
  return gulp.src('css/**/*.css', {cwd: 'src'})
    .pipe(csslint({
      'compatible-vendor-prefixes': false,
      'box-sizing': false
    }))
    .pipe(concatCss('app.css'))
    .pipe(minifyCss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/css'));
});

gulp.task('html', function () {
  return gulp.src('**/*.html', {cwd: 'src'})
    .pipe(htmltidy())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: What does this history api fallback do?

Comment: It's a middleware which allow to serve one page app. By default brosersync will try to load the HTML page corresponding to the URL entered which obviously don't work with one page app. The middleware allow browsersync to use browserhistory to load URL for one page apps.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this works since it looks great. You said "try to load the html page corresponding to the url entered" but I don't quite understand what you mean. I think this may be the best solution I'm aware of now so I'll try it asap.

Comment: One more thing - is gulp really required? It seems like I could use pure npm and browsersync to achieve this, no? Course, I wouldn't know how to translate this to remove gulp

Comment: Gulp simplify things a lot, there is interest in a pure npm script based solution on browsersync bugtracker but not anything working as good as with gulp. You can have a look here it will maybe work for you : https://github.com/BrowserSync/recipes/issues/2 . When I say  "try to load the html page corresponding to the url entered" if you request <server_name>/mypage browsersync will look for a mypage.html file in your app directory, which of course it won't find, since url are handled by a router in your onepage app.

Comment: Well that validates my instinct that there should be a more pure solution. I wasn't sure if your solution was just the one you knew or if it was the best/most elegant solution. I'm trying to set up a new front end devops process and want to minimize the middleware type of stuff. I'm not going to try swimming against the current for now given that I'm new to the domain.

Comment: Sorry, haven't tested yet still as I've been working late and was traveling. I'm actually not sure what it does. Does browsersync run an http server?

Comment: Yes it does, it also come with an administration UI, and synchronisation between browser/devices (if you launch the same page served by browsersync on different browser/devices you actions are emitted to all of them)

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate you following up.

Comment: I made some progress tonight (had to set up gulp, etc), but it looks like i have some debugging to do still:  **[23:32:09] Task 'js' is not in your gulpfile
[23:32:09] Please check the documentation for proper gulpfile formatting.**  Also, i think i had to add the browser-sync dependency which isn't in your code sample. I'll continue debugging the error tomorrow night...

Comment: Yes the code do not show everything, It's just the reload part, I'll edit and complete the answer.

Comment: Ok I've added a stipped down version of the build file I use, It contain everything you might find useful, if you dont just remove them. But it shoulb be complete and work almost as this. Just remember to change the path of directory and files to fit to your project. I use browserify in this example, feel free to remove it or change it for webpack for example.

Comment: Ok, I'm really close now. I just have to get my css concatenated properly, etc. The css task was throwing some errors so I'm working then through. I should have it done this weekend

Comment: This solution is **perfect** - exactly what I was hoping for. As a bonus I got gulp integrated so I can start doing some more sophisticated processing of my static content.